# how to check is user login or not in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using this code for user which can't access page without login ,but it is not working to prevent the user .

```
if(! $this->session->userdata('id'))
         return redirect('Login');
   $this->load->view('public/dashboard');
```

Comment: it means your session not stored..

Comment: are u saving the information in `id` session array??  y r u using return? share the code where u r saving session values, also note that, with `redirect()` no need to use return.

Comment: my session is stored but still don't prevent the user to access the dashboard page .

Comment: if session is set than try: `if(intval($this->session->userdata('id')) <= 0) {
  redirect('Login');
}
$this->load->view('public/dashboard');`

Comment: Try to give us some extra info, like your login area and what is stored in `$this->session->userdata('id')` and how do you stored? [the line of code I mean]. @HarshJain

Answer (score 0):

Try this for start. But generally i use another strategy, i make the if statements in Views. 
If this is not works for you, i will check further.

```
 if(! $this->session->userdata('id')){
       $this->load->view('Login'); }
else {
       $this->load->view('public/dashboard'); }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ,but still not fully correct .When i m directly write the url route its gives an access of dashboard page .

Comment: you have right, the problem is not in your syntax. sorry for that, i will come back with the right answer

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is something like this

application / core / MY_Controller.php

```
<?php 

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $route = $this->router->directory . $this->router->fetch_class();

        // echo $route;

        // Ignore any controllers not to be effected 
        $ignore = array(
            'dirname/controllername',
        );

        // If the user has not logged in will redirect back to login

        if (!$this->session->userdata('id') && !in_array($route, $ignore)) {
            $this->session->unset_userdata('id');
            redirect($this->config->item('base_url') . 'login');
        }
    }
}
```

On the controller change CI_Controller to MY_Controller

```
class Example extends MY_Controller {

     public function index() {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $this->session->userdata('id') == "")
{
   redirect('Login');
}
else
{

   redirect('dashboard');
}
```

here Login and dashboard both are controller names.